# Question about proper use of "pedantic"

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

Would the following sentences be correct?

> You were more concerned with being
>   pedantic.
>
> I felt you were being pedantic.
>
> You wanted to have a pedantic
>   conversation.

Comment: At least there's nothing ungrammatical about them. Could you elaborate on why you have doubts about their correctness?

Comment: how very meta...

Comment: LOL! +1 for Ken's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are syntactically correct and all seem fine to me as semantically correct. The third one seems a little fuzzy, but I am perfectly fine with calling other non-human things pedantic (e.g., [gcc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc)). I'd argue that one down to a style issue.